# How to tackle a dataset that has multiple same date values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a large data set that I'm trying to produce a time series using ARIMA. However
some of the data in the date column has multiple rows with the same date.

The data for the dates was entered this way in the data set as it was not known the exact date of the event, hence unknown dates where entered for the first of that month(biased). Known dates have been entered correctly in the data set.

```
2016-01-01    10035
2015-01-01    5397
2013-01-01    4567
2014-01-01    4343
2017-01-01    3981
2011-01-01    2049
```

Ideally I want to randomise the dates within the month so they are not the same. I have the code to randomise the date but I cannot find a way to replace the data with the date ranges.

```
import random
import time
    
def str_time_prop(start, end, time_format, prop):

    stime = time.mktime(time.strptime(start, time_format))
    etime = time.mktime(time.strptime(end, time_format))

    ptime = stime + prop * (etime - stime)

    return time.strftime(time_format, time.localtime(ptime))


def random_date(start, end, prop):
    return str_time_prop(start, end, '%Y-%m-%d', prop)

# check if the random function works
print(random_date("2021-01-02", "2021-01-11", random.random()))
```

The code above I use to generate a random date within a date range but I'm stuggling to find a way to replace the dates.

Any help/guidance would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import random
import time
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [
            "2016-01-01",
            "2015-01-01",
            "2013-01-01",
            "2014-01-01",
            "2017-01-01",
            "2011-01-01",
        ],
        "value": [10035, 5397, 4567, 4343, 3981, 2049],
    }
)
print(df)
# Output
         date  value
0  2016-01-01  10035
1  2015-01-01   5397
2  2013-01-01   4567
3  2014-01-01   4343
4  2017-01-01   3981
5  2011-01-01   2049
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df["date"] = [
    random_date("2011-01-01", "2022-04-17", random.random()) for _ in range(df.shape[0])
]

print(df)
# Ouput
         date  value
0  2013-12-30  10035
1  2016-06-17   5397
2  2018-01-26   4567
3  2012-02-14   4343
4  2014-06-26   3981
5  2019-07-03   2049
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data in the date column has multiple rows with the same date, and you want to randomize the dates within the month, you could group by the year and month and select only those who have the day equal 1. Then, use [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) to find the last day of the month for that particular year, and use that information when replacing the timestamp's day. Change the `FIRST_DAY` and `last_day` values to match your desired range.

```py
import pandas as pd
import calendar
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# group multiple rows with the same year, month and day equal 1
grouped = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month, df['date'].dt.day==1])

FIRST_DAY = 2 # set for the desired range
df_list = []
for n,g in grouped:
    last_day = calendar.monthrange(n[0], n[1])[1] # get last day for this month and year
    g['New_Date'] = g['date'].apply(lambda d:
        d.replace(day=np.random.randint(FIRST_DAY,last_day+1))
    )
    df_list.append(g)

new_df = pd.concat(df_list)
print(new_df)
```

Output from *new_df*

```py
        date    num   New_Date
2 2013-01-01   4567 2013-01-08
3 2014-01-01   4343 2014-01-21
1 2015-01-01   5397 2015-01-30
0 2016-01-01  10035 2016-01-16
4 2017-01-01   3981 2017-01-12
```